# Importing a variable from one python script to another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `script1.py` which calls `script2.py (subprocess.call([sys.executable, "script2.py"])`. But `script2.py` needs variable `x` that is known in `script1.py`. I tried a very simple `import x from script1`, but it seems not to work.

Is that the right approach to use?
For example:

```
#script1.py
import subprocess, sys
##subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\...\\Desktop\\script2.py'], shell=True)
##os.system("C:\\...\\Desktop\\script2.py")
subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\Desktop\\script2.py", shell=True)
print "BLAH"
x = BO

#script2.py
from script1 import x
print "HELLO"
print x
```

All 3 cases of calling script2 (subprocess.call, os.system, subprocess.Popen ) do not work. I get "BLAH" but not "HELLO".

Comment: [Correct syntax is](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules): `from script1 import x`

Comment: Yea, I wrote so in my code actually :) as I said it does not work!

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand me well. I wrote it correctly: from script1 import x and it does not work.

Comment: Please explain *it does not work*?

Comment: ok. Both scripts are not small scripts, doing a lot of things. The second one which is importing variable from first one is doing some transformations according to the variable t. If I set t as a fix value, for instance t=50 than everything works fine, but If I set t=x where x is imported from script1 than this process never stops, it works and works ...

Comment: Please, does anyone know where is the problem? It look like very simple,but I do not know!

Comment: Post some small sample scripts that can reproduce your error.

Comment: Posted within edited question

Comment: Try: `print subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, 'C:\\...\\Desktop\\script2.py'])`, this will print the output of `script2.py`.

Comment: I do not see any error message neither written BLAH nor HELLO words in the Python Interpreter window ?! But the script is still running and running...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K8wE2yeQ, Do you've an infinite loop in `script2.py?`

Comment: The code looks like it is written above (in the question). Nothing more. I wanted to test it with this small example. Is there a loop? I do not see anything.

Answer (score 37):

The correct syntax is:

```
from script1 import x
```

So, literally, "from script1.py import the "x" object."

Comment: What if i want to modify the value of x in script2 and print new value in script1?

Comment: @human torch did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same question

Comment: @Quastiat That sounds like bad design - you should always be importing constant values/functions. Perhaps you need to make a copy?

Comment: @TerryA Yeah thanks I figured that as well, I implemented a class `DataManipulater()` where i input my raw data and can apply some adjustments to it via the classes methods. Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @Quastiat It's a bit hard without context but classes do seem like the way to go yea

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
from script1 import x
```

I just ran the following pieces of code and it worked

**script1:**

`c = 10`

**script2:**

```
from script1 import c
print c
```

The second script printed the integer 10 as you should expect.

**Oct 17 Edit:**
As it stands the code will either not produce the "Hello" as indicated or will go into an infinite loop.  A couple of issues:

As it stands, BO is undefined.  When you execute script1, the subprocess of script2 is opened.  When script2 calls script1, it will print out blah but fail on x=BO as BO is undefined.

So, if you fix that by specifying BO with say a string, it will go into an infinite loop (each script calling the other one and printing x, Hello and Blah).

One potential way to fix it is to pass x through a function call.  So, script2 could take x as a function parameter and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: this is probably no longer valid since the question has been edited

Answer (score 5):

Your code is looping because the `subprocess.Popen` call is in the module initialization code, so it will be called by script2 when importing script1 (creating a new script2 process that also imports script1 ...)

[The recommended way](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) of having a python file usable as both a script and a module is to use the `__name__` variable

```
#script1.py

x = BO

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import subprocess, sys
    subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\Desktop\\script2.py", shell=True)
    print "BLAH"
```

But also consider this only works for *constants*. If `x` can change at runtime you will need an actual interprocess communication method.

Answer (score 2):

script1.py:

```
x = 2
from script2 import *
```

script2.py:

```
from script1 import x
print x
```

Answer (score 2):

Script 0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from script1 import x

print x
```

Script 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
x = "Hello world"
```

Output:

```
Hello world
```

So yeah it does work, no need for sub processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must refer at the variable by prefixing its module name (i.e. script1.x) in script2.py

Answer (score 0):

The method being used is more complex than is necessary.  After fixing BO (I assumed it is meant as a string literal, so I quoted it), and assuming the scripts are co-located, you can call script2 and get the result you are after.

See the following:

```
#script1.py
print "BLAH"
x = "BO"

#script2.py
from script1 import x
print "HELLO"
print x

$ python script2.py 
BLAH
HELLO
BO
```