# share variable (data from file) among multiple python scripts with not loaded duplicates

Tags: python, bash, shared-memory

I would like to load a big matrix contained in the `matrix_file.mtx`. This load must be made once. Once the variable `matrix` is loaded into the memory, I would like many python scripts to share it with not duplicates in order to have a memory efficient multiscript program in bash (or python itself). I can imagine some pseudocode like this:

```
# Loading and sharing script:
import share
matrix = open("matrix_file.mtx","r")
share.send_to_shared_ram(matrix, as_variable('matrix'))

# Shared matrix variable processing script_1
import share
pointer_to_matrix = share.share_variable_from_ram('matrix')
type(pointer_to_matrix)
# output: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

# Shared matrix variable processing script_2
import share
pointer_to_matrix = share.share_variable_from_ram('matrix')
type(pointer_to_matrix)
# output: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
...
```

The idea is `pointer_to_matrix` to point to `matrix` in RAM, which is only once loaded by the n scripts (not n times). They are separately called from a bash script (or if possible form a python main):

```
$ python Load_and_share.py
$ python script_1.py -args string &
$ python script_2.py -args string &
$ ...
$ python script_n.py -args string &
```

I'd also be interested in solutions via hard disk, i.e. `matrix` could be stored at disk while the `share` object access to it as being required. Nonetheless, the object (a kind of pointer) in RAM can be seen as the whole matrix.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which OS do your scripts run under?

Comment: They are running in Ubuntu 14.04, my scripts are written in Python2.7 I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289171/importing-a-variable-from-one-python-script-to-another, but I dont know if the serialized variable is really shared or is actually loaded n times.

Comment: Lookup mmap -- memory mapped file support. You can open the saved `matrix` file in separate python scripts as necessary. If you can open read only (PROT_READ but not PROT_WRITE), copying will be minimized or eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Between the [`mmap` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) and [`numpy.frombuffer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy.frombuffer), this is fairly easy:

```
import mmap
import numpy as np

with open("matrix_file.mtx","rb") as matfile:
    mm = mmap.mmap(matfile.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    # Optionally, on UNIX-like systems in Py3.3+, add:
    # os.posix_fadvise(matfile.fileno(), 0, len(mm), os.POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED)
    # to trigger background read in of the file to the system cache,
    # minimizing page faults when you use it

matrix = np.frombuffer(mm, np.uint8)
```

Each process would perform this work separately, and get a read only view of the same memory. You'd change the `dtype` to something other than `uint8` as needed. Switching to `ACCESS_WRITE` would allow modifications to shared data, though it would require synchronization and possibly explicit calls to `mm.flush` to actually ensure the data was reflected in other processes.

A more complex solution that follows your initial design more closely might be to uses [`multiprocessing.SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) to create a connectable shared "server" for data, allowing a single common store of data to be registered with the manager and returned to as many users as desired; creating an `Array` (based on `ctypes` types) with the correct type on the manager, then `register`-ing a function that returns the same shared `Array` to all callers would work too (each caller would then convert the returned `Array` via `numpy.frombuffer` as before). It's much more involved (it would be easier to have a single Python process initialize an `Array`, then launch `Process`es that would share it automatically thanks to `fork` semantics), but it's the closest to the concept you describe.