# How do you override a variable in a calling script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a seemingly simple problem but can't find/figure out a solution.

I have two files and want to pass a variable from one script to the other, and update a variable in the calling script. I want to do this without modifying file_b:

file_a.py

```py
inputs = {
    "input_1": "value"
}

# Import/run file_b.py

print(outputs)
```

file_b.py

```py
outputs = inputs.get("input_1")
```

I've tried this which is very close:

```py
global inputs
inputs = {
    "input_1": "value"
}
global outputs
outputs = []

exec(open("script_b.py").read(), globals())

print(outputs)
```

The exec method is able to send the variables to file_b but not get the outputs back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not `import file_a` in file_b ?

Comment: I need to execute file_a and I can't modify file_b

Comment: What are you expecting? It should print `value` right? It is working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a variable from one python script to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289171/importing-a-variable-from-one-python-script-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example I posted actually does work.

I tried to simplify the args passed to file_b by using this instead which doesn't work:

```py
global inputs
inputs = {
    "input_1": "value"
}
global outputs
outputs = []

exec(open("script_b.py").read(), {"inputs": inputs, "outputs": outputs})

print(outputs)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not, edit your question with this updated information instead.