# How to pass value entered in textbox to flask in text format from django?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django and flask.
I want to pass the value entered in textbox from django to flask.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

# Create your views here.

def form(request):
    return render(request,'hello/index.html')
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


  <form action="output">
    
    Enter name: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"> <br/>
  
    <input type="submit" ><br/>
  
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
     
     return "hello" 
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the flask i should get the values entered in django textbox....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the question, but I want to know whether there is any other way to pass data.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

# Create your views here.

def form(request):
    return render(request,'hello/index.html')

def output(request):
    name1=request.GET["name"]
    if not name1:
        name1=0
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/'+str(name1)).json()
    #name = response.text
    return render(request, 'hello/index.html', {'out': response['out']})
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


  <form action="output" method="GET">
    
    Enter name: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"> <br/>
  
    <input type="submit" ><br/>
  
</form>
<div>
  {{out}}
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

flask file

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/<name>',methods=['GET'])
def index(name):
     return jsonify({'out' : "Hello"+  " "+str(name)})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.(https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223338/discussion-between-divyessh-and-vignesh-v)

Answer (score 0):

change form tag in html as:

```
<form method="GET" action="output">
```

change urlpatterns in urls.py as:

```
path('output', views.output ,name ='output'),
```

add the following in your views.py:

```
def output(request):
    data = request.GET['name']
    return render(request, 'hello/**any template**.html',{'data' : data})
```

this will pass a variable data to your index.html
Now you can use that in you any of templates with jinja.

Comment: how will  i pass the entered value to flask webservice

Comment: make data as a global variable and then import it in flask file

Comment: Let me share the link with you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289171/importing-a-variable-from-one-python-script-to-another\

Comment: I found a solution...please check my answer

Comment: yeah what is it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223338/discussion-between-divyessh-and-vignesh-v).

Comment: i have posted it

Comment: got it , join through link